# Calculating the maximum number of edges for 4 specifically-shaped connected graphs with n nodes

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I'm trying to calculate the maximum number of edges for 4 specifically-shaped connected graphs with n nodes (see the attached / below picture for the 4 specific shapes). So the first type of graph, the square, would come close to 2n edges for higher numbers of n, but I need something much more accurate for n between 0 and 100. For n=7, the max might be 8 but for n=8, the max might be 10 - both different and not at all close to 2n.

[Visual representation of the 4 specifically-shaped connected graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbDZ7.png)

I'm basically looking for 4 different functions which express the maximum number of edges for n nodes for these 4 different types of graphs.

This question might be quite vague since I'm not formally trained in math - but appreciate any clarifying questions / attempts at an answer.

Comment: you want formula for the "building block" or the tilling?

Comment: For the first one, the square, are you given that $n$ is a square?  If not, does the graph have to be a rectangle?  What answer do you want for $n=5$ and $n=6$?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Re the first question, I'm looking for a formula for the number of nodes n between 0 and 100 - so it would include both the building block and the tilling depending on what n is. Re the second question, yes n is a square. For n=5, my max is 5; for n=6, my max is 7.

Comment: @STS please use @ username or else  we dont get notified. you men say n=90, then you need a formula for tilling of 90 of type1 , another formula for  n=90, then you need a formula for tilling of 90 of type2 ,so on ?

Comment: @LaylaBailey, yes exactly.

Comment: @RossMillikan, to clarify - for n=6, the overall shape would be a rectangle made up of two squares. For n=5, it would be an "unfinished rectangle". Just realized my answer above isn't accurate.

Comment: If you have a rectangular grid of $k \times m$ points the number of points is $km$.  The number of edges is $k(m-1)+(k-1)m$.  If you can factor $n$ into two close factors this will be optimal. Having an extra edge may help if $n$ does not factor nicely.  For example, if $n=23$  you could have $22$ edges if you make a linear chain.  If you make a $2 \times 11$ grid plus one edge you have $32$.  If you make a $4 \times 5$ grid plus three edges you have $34$

Answer (score 0):

For the square grid if you have a rectangular grid of $k \times m$ points the number of points is $km$.  The number of edges is $k(m-1)+(k-1)m$ where one term counts horizontal edges and the other vertical.  If you can factor $n$ into two close factors this will be optimal. Having an extra edge may help if $n$ does not factor nicely.  For example, if $n=23$  you could have $22$ edges if you make a linear chain.  If you make a $2 \times 11$ grid plus one edge you have $32$.  If you make a $4 \times 5$ grid plus three edges you have $34.$  I don't think there is an easy formula.

Comment: Thanks - any thoughts on what the formula could be for the other 3 types of shapes?

Comment: It should be reasonably easy to compute the number of vertices and sides in a complete array of the other shapes by looking at how many you add with each column and row.